# What happens when the [] operator fails and I need an assert on that?

Tags: c++, c++11, assert, static-assert

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() {
  int a[] = { 21, 213, 45 };
  static_assert(a[22], "error for a\n");
  return (0);
}
```

I have a lookup table shaped like an array of `int`, I need to check at compile time if the use of the `[]` operator could possibly lead to a read that is out of the scope.

I know that a `static_assert` needs basically 2 things:

- a constant expression
- the given expression should return a `bool` or be convertible/equivalent to a `bool`

Now in `g++ 4.8.1` an `initializer_list` should be a constant expression in C++11, and I don't know how many times I have seen an `if` construct written like this `if(arr[N]){...}`; so what is wrong with this assert ?

Comment: The argument for the static assert must be resolvable at compile time. `a` is an array of `ints`, `a[22]` returns an `int`, the value of which will not be known until runtime.  The fact that it's out of bounds won't stop you examining it.

Basically, whether an array access is out of bounds or not is almost always going to only be known at **runtime** so this in an innappropriate place for a static_assert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can generalize what you want with a little template magic.

```
template<typename T,int N> constexpr bool bounds_check(T (&array)[N], int i)
{
    return i < N;
}
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/kj51N0

Answer (score 2):

Accessing out of the array bounds is *undefined behaviour*. So, literally anything could happen.

Static assertions are all about *compile time* failures. This will not be captured until *run time*: too late.

Comment: so having an initializer_list with the property of being a constant expression it's of no use here ? It's a waste of compile-time informations in my opinion, i find hard to believe that I need to wait the runtime to check on that

Answer (score 2):

`a[22]` isn't a constant expression. Plus, it has no range check because access to native arrays is rewritten to `*(a + 22)` by the compiler. To get a range check you'd need to build `a` as a `std::array` plus the C++ library would need to have a range check enabled, which some do but only in debug mode.

What would work here I think is if you did `static_assert(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) > 22, "a not large enough")`

Comment: so an initializer_list is useless for an assert ?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I didn't try it.

Comment: @user2485710: I don't see how an initializer_list is relevant to the question.

Comment: @ZanLynx it's a constant expression ... and I tried it, but it dind't did the trick or changed anything in the equation.

Comment: @user2485710: the initializer may be constant but what was initialized is not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

```
int a[] = { 21, 213, 45 };
static_assert(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) > 22, "error for a\n");
return (0);
```

But that's a very weird check to do. It only works if the index (`22`) and the size of `a` being known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<std::size_t Index, typename T, std::size_t N>
T& at( T(&a)[N] ) {
  static_assert( Index < N, "Out of bounds" );
  return a[Index];
}
template<std::size_t Index, typename T, std::size_t N>
T& at( std::array<T,N>& a ) {
  static_assert( Index < N, "Out of bounds" );
  return a[Index];
}
template<std::size_t Index, typename T, std::size_t N>
T const& at( std::array<T,N> const& a ) {
  static_assert( Index < N, "Out of bounds" );
  return a[Index];
}
```

use:

```
int main() {
  int a[] = { 21, 213, 45 };
  int x = at<22>(a); // fails to compile
  return (0);
}
```